# Lotus Notes to SharePoint migration fromuing Quest tool

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lotus-notes

I am new to SharePoint 2013 ,kindly share me any link to complete the SharePoint migration from Lotus notes using quest tool? And share me to step by step approach how to do it?
IS there any third party tools are available share here

Comment: Try this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91b369/lotus-notes-to-sharepoint-migration-using-quest617/ but please be informed DELL's solution has its own community @ http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/sharepoint-for-all/f/4800